# Creating rectangle with SDL_FillRect

Tags: c++, sdl

my code is not really working (no errors, but the rectangle is not shown).
I have 3 classes: CFramework, CRectangle, CGame.
Whats wrong/missing?

My CFramework class initiates SDL and sets the video mode etc.

**CRectangle.hpp:**

```
#ifndef  RECTANGLE_HPP
#define RECTANGLE_HPP

#include "Framework.hpp"

class CRectangle
{
    public:    
        CRectangle ();
        void createRectangle (int x, int y, int width, int height, int r, int g, int b);

    private:
        SDL_Surface *m_pScreen; // Pointer at the screen of CFramework
        SDL_Rect m_Rect;
};


#endif
```

**CRectangle.cpp:**

```
#include "Rectangle.hpp"


// Konstruktor
//
// Aufgabe: Zeiger auf Screen holen
//
CRectangle::CRectangle ()
{
    // Zeiger auf Screen holen
    m_pScreen = g_pFramework->GetScreen ();

} // Konstruktor

// createRectangle
//
// Aufgabe: Viereck erstellen
//
void CRectangle::createRectangle (int x, int y, int width, int height, int r, int g, int b)
{
        m_Rect.x = x;
        m_Rect.y = y;
        m_Rect.w = width;
        m_Rect.h = height;
        SDL_FillRect(m_pScreen, &m_Rect, SDL_MapRGB(m_pScreen->format, r, g, b));
} // createRectangle
```

**CGame.cpp:**

```
... // just the important stuff
    m_pRectangleMenu = new CRectangle;
    m_pRectangleMenu->createRectangle(100,100,400,400,233,34,34);
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// just the important stuff
m_pRectangleMenu = new CRectangle;
m_pRectangleMenu->createRectangle(100,100,400,400,233,34,34);
```

Well since you didn't include an "SDL_Flip(screen_variable)"...maybe that's your problem. If not, you should post up unto the SDL_Flip().

Reagan

Comment: I just fixed it by putting my code in the while-loop, totally forgot about that. That loop also flips the surface, so your answer is right. Thanks